# Yii2 Moving folder mdm-admin of mdmsoft and xml view appeared

Tags: php, xml, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

I'm using Yii2 to develop my web app. But when I using yii2-admin of mdmsoft with version 3 for prettyURL, I move folder of yii2-admin to modules folder, and change main.php like this:

```
'bootstrap' => [
    'admin'
],
'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // or use 'yii\rbac\DbManager'
    ],
'modules' => [
    'rbac' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\rbac\Module',
            'layout' => '@backend/views/layouts/admin',
            'controllerMap' => [
                'assignment' => [
                    'class' => 'app\modules\rbac\controllers\AssignmentController',
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
],
'as access' => [
    'class' => 'mdm\admin\classes\AccessControl',
    'allowActions' => [
        '*',
    ]
],
```

But when I access mydomain/rbac/assignment or mydomain.com/rbac/route ,... it's just a xml view, nothing more?

How I can fix it?

Comment: You should not modify anything under `vendor` folder. It's managed by Composer. What's the point of moving `yii2-admin` folder?

Comment: I doesn't modify anything in vendor folder, I just copy this and move into the modules folder to use it.

Comment: You should not do that. You can include external modules from `vendor` folder.

Comment: I re-fixed like you go, but it's still have xml view